# ScrollView height doesn't compress on iPhone 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a hierarchy of views with a UIScrollView in the middle like this:

-UIView
--UIScrollView
---UIView

I'm using autolayout and storyboards. I've designed the storyboard to layout correctly on an iPhone5, and tried to use constraints to make this outer view expand and contract to the other screen sizes. It expands perfectly for the 6 / 6+, but it does not contract correctly for the 4. Here is a screenshot of my storyboard along with some of the constraints:

[image]

The outer view may seem excessive, but I need it to draw a rounded border as I was unsuccessful drawing the border directly around the scrollview. Here is what the screen looks like when rendered on the 4" screen (this is what it should look like):

[image]

But then when I run it on a 3.5" screen, that view does not shrink. It just spills off the bottom of the screen.

[image]

I've been going in circles trying to figure this out for hours now, and am getting nowhere. I've played with content hugging and compression resistance, along with modifying just about every constraint in the storyboard. I don't want to get into fixed heights, since that defeats the very purpose of autolayout. Can anyone suggest what I should look at? Thanks!

EDIT: I should also point out that I know that the the bottom button will be truncated when the outer scrollview and view are shortened. That's fine for now. My objective is to get that outer view (the one with the rounded border) to shorten so that it's bottom is 20 pixels above the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem recently. [And I found this tutorial](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/), I put a `contentView` as a child view of `scrollView`. Put 4 margin constraints (top, left, bottom and right) between `scrollView` and `contentView`, it will affect the `contentSize` of `UIScrollView`.

Then, put 2 constraints between `UIScrollView` and its superView about `height` and `width`, let `UIScrollView` has the same size as its superView.

In the result, the `contentView` will be expanded as the same size as the superView of scrollView. In my iPhone 4s simulator, it works fine.

---

The UI components on the `contentView` needs to configure constraints between them and `contentView`. My buttons on the bottoms set the bottom constraints between `contentView`'s bottom and their bottom. Some UI components set constraint between the top of `contentView`.

Comment: Yes, I have all of this set up, but still no luck. Looks like I'm going to wind up having to change the height of the content view at run time and rolling up from there. Thanks for the suggestion.